# Generating a certain amount random words from an external file

Tags: python, random

This maybe really easy but cannot find a solution. I have a text file which has 10 5-letter words within it, what I want it to do is to pick 9 out of the 10 words at random and print them.

Currently I've got this:

```
import random
randomword = [line.strip() for line in open('10.txt')]
print (random.choice(randomword))
```

This generates one random word from the list of 10 - but I want it to generate me 9 out of 10 without any repeating.
Can anyone give me a simple solution?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to choose a certain number of unique elements from a population:

```
random.sample(randomword, 9)
```

You could probably do it without reading the entire file in, but I suppose that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
from random import shuffle    
data = open('file.txt','r').read().split()
shuffle(data)
data[:9]
```

Answer (score 0):

And another solution: pick a random number from the range and print all the entries that do not match the number you picked.  In effect you randomly pick the one to leave out, rhather than trying to pick the nine to print.